# Window.Visibility won't update through trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datatrigger

I'm trying to set a trigger to hide my window whenever a property in my ViewModel changes. I tried using the same trigger on a different element and that worked exactly as expected, so it appears that I cannot change the visibility property of a window using a trigger. Are there any workarounds I can use to hide my window?

```
<Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Window" BasedOn="{StaticResource Shell}">

        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="Left" Value="{Binding SecondDisplayLeftSide}"/>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShellType}" Value="InstructorMultiDisplay">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>

        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
</Window.Style>
```

Comment: Works fine for me, I'm guessing there's probably something wrong with your binding.